# Why is Php pbkdf2 output is coming out different from golang?

Tags: php, go, cryptography, pbkdf2

I am trying to figure this out for hours. I have used the same pbkdf2 algorithm in PHP and golang and somehow the output's different.

**Golang**

```
saltString := "e7655f410aa38e1ca05de7a7fd8fb84c"
password := "vibhor123"
salt, err := hex.DecodeString(saltString)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(salt)
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%x", pbkdf2.Key([]byte(input.Password), salt, 4096, sha256.Size, sha256.New)))
```

**Output**

```
3d70b8536a7b26d67419e220e1c244a1cc9431a3c23999c2f993d8a3a4dda13a
```

**PHP**

```
$salt = "e7655f410aa38e1ca05de7a7fd8fb84c";
$password = "vibhor123";
echo(hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, 4096));
```

**Output**

```
a8595b29ddb1a7819bae7e9d8809f26f053b3877197ed44e05e279459a826c64
```

According to my understanding both should match.

Comment: In the PHP code the salt must be hex decoded, i.e. in `hash_pbkdf2` replace the third parameter with `hex2bin($salt)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [`hash_pbkdf2`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)'s salt must be presented as a binary string, not as a hex string. Simply use `hex2bin` to convert it to the raw binary. See https://3v4l.org/IIXFM.

```php
$salt = "e7655f410aa38e1ca05de7a7fd8fb84c";
$password = "vibhor123";
echo(hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, hex2bin($salt), 4096));
```

```
3d70b8536a7b26d67419e220e1c244a1cc9431a3c23999c2f993d8a3a4dda13a
```